# Laravel 5.1 Token mismatch between POST header token and token in session

Tags: php, laravel, token, mismatch

UPDATE 2:
It is definately generating a whole new session & token upon executing the POST. My sessions are set up to be stored in files and I can physically see a new session get created straight after posting.

I cannot still find a reason for this. Any help is appreciated!

---

UPDATE:
Upon further tracing of issue I found in `class VerifyCsrfToken` that the validation is done by this line of code in `protected function tokensMatch($request)`

```
$token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');

return Str::equals($request->session()->token(), $token);
```

I copy the token from initial page load (and check its session value) and they match.

```
Token in session & hidden (login Page first load)= wHszQpffJC0gIov17pd2ZbPqtdbFq7yZh3U2QlOe
```

But the tokens are different when the `POST` takes place and they are compared. Somehow the token in session has been changed. I check like this:

```
echo 'Token from request= ' . $token;
echo 'Token from session= ' . $request->session()->token();
```

and I get this:

```
Token from request= wHszQpffJC0gIov17pd2ZbPqtdbFq7yZh3U2QlOe 
Token from session= sfquUx6MhPaqdMR862kDZh8qYmpKDJ0Rbdghq1iA
```

I do this on a fresh browser / login attempt. Why would the token in session be different than the one carried across from the login page?

---

ORIGINAL Q:
I am getting the above error on a fresh L5.1 install and cannot (after reading numerous links) get this problem solved. I am new to Laravel. Appreciate any suggestions.

My form looks like this:

```
    @extends('admin.layouts.default')

    @section('content')

    <div id="form" class="login">

        <img src="{{ $logo }}" class="logo"/>

        @include('admin.partials.message')

        {!! Form::open(['url' => '/login', 'class'=>'form']) !!}

            <div class="form-group">

                {!! Form::label('email', 'Email:', ['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'email', 'required'=>'1']) !!}

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                {!! Form::label('password', 'Password:', ['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::password('password', ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'password', 'required'=>'1']) !!}

            </div>

            <div class="form-group text-left">

                {!! Form::checkbox('remember',  '1', null, ['id'=>'remember']) !!}
                {!! Form::label('remember', 'Remember Me', ['class'=>'control-label']) !!}

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                {!! Form::submit('Sign In', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}

                <a href="/reset-password" class="text-muted">Forgot Your Password?</a>

            </div>

        {!! Form::close() !!}

    </div>

    <?php dd(session()); ?>
@stop
```

My routes look like this:

```
   /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Freely available routes for login, registration, password reset etc
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'guest'
    ], function(){

        // Register
        Route::get('register', ['uses' => 'RegistrationController@create', 'as' => 'registration.create']);
        Route::post('register', ['uses' => 'RegistrationController@store', 'as' => 'registration.create']);

        // Activate
        Route::get('register/activate/{uuid}', ['uses' => 'RegistrationController@activate', 'as' => 'registration.activate']); // Pattern matched

        // Login/logout
        Route::get('login', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin', 'as' => 'session.create']);
        Route::post('login', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin', 'as' => 'session.create']);
        Route::get('logout', ['uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout', 'as' => 'session.destroy']);

        // Forgot password
        Route::get('reset-password', ['uses' => 'SessionController@reset_password', 'as' => 'session.reset_password']);

        // Change password
        Route::get('change-password', ['uses' => 'SessionController@change_password', 'as' => 'session.change_password']);
    });
```

The token on page load and session look the same, generated by formBuilder.

Session:

```
 #attributes: array:1 [▼
        "_token" => "EE5qv7mhhyI0cutpXOgU6jgvUR2R58RubQ5pC128"
      ]
```

Page HTML:

```
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="EE5qv7mhhyI0cutpXOgU6jgvUR2R58RubQ5pC128">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem it turns out was that I had set the session variable `secure` to `true` in the `www/config/session.php` file. This was causing Laravel to expect requests via `HTTPS` which my development environment does not have set up, and thus causing the server to treat each `GET` or `POST` as a new request.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I am getting this exact same issue but `secure` in the session config is set to `false`

Any other ideas around this would be awesome. I have checked the domain for sessions and also the time on the server and in php. 

My code works find locally and on a Ubuntu Server php v5.5.9 but in Red Hat php v5.6 it's not playing ball.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem in laravel 5.2.29, I have set secure in session.php to false but the problem remains the same. Any leads on this will be helpful. Thanks in advance.